# Finding a set of vectors that spans the solution set of the equation?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

first, do I have to solve for $x, y, z$ and $w$ in terms of.

so $w=v$, and $z=u$.

from here on, what do i have to do?

Answer (score 1):

$w - 2z = x - 2y, 3w - 2z = -2x + y \to 2w = -3x + 3y \to w = -\dfrac{3}{2}x + \dfrac{3}{2}y \to 2w - 4z = 2x - 4y \to -3x+3y -4z = 2x-4y \to 4z = -5x+7y \to z = -\dfrac{5}{4}x + \dfrac{7}{4}y \to (x,y,z,w) = (x,y,-\frac{3}{2}x+\frac{3}{2}y,-\frac{5}{4}x+\frac{7}{4}y) = x(1,0,-\frac{3}{2},\frac{5}{4}) + y(0,1,\frac{3}{2},\frac{7}{4})$. Can you "see" the vectors $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ from this ?

Comment: are the u and v vectors 1,0,-1.5,5/4 and 0,1,1.5,7/4 ?

Comment: Yes, they are !